# Append line at the end of each file

Tags: bash

I have files in a dir.
I need to append a new line and the file name at the end of each file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do:

```
for f in *; do echo >> $f; echo $f >> $f; done
```

- First echo a new-line, then echo the filename.
- The `>>` says "append at the end of the file".

Comment: That doesn't add the requested newline before the file name.

Comment: What if the filename contains \?  `printf '\n%s\n' "$f"`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  aioobe's answer has been updated to show the -e flag that I didn't see when I first answered this.  Thus I'm now just showing an example which includes a directory and how to eliminate the directory name:

```
#!/bin/bash
for fn in dir/* 
do
  shortname=${fn/#*\//}
  echo -e "\n$shortname" >> $fn
done
```

If you want the directory name, take out the `shortname=${fn/#*\//}` line and replace $shortname with $fn in the echo.

Answer (score 0):

Let `xargs` do the looping:

```
# recursive, includes directory name
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I% bash -c 'echo -e "\n%" >> %'
```

or

```
# non-recursive, doesn't include directory name
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \; | xargs -I% bash -c 'echo -e "\n%" >> %'
```

or

```
# non-recursive, doesn't include directory name
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I% bash -c 'echo -e "\n%" >> %'
```

or

```
# recursive, doesn't include directory name
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I% bash -c 'f=%; echo -e "\n${f##*/}" >> %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `ex` (or vim) :

```
ex -c 'args **/*' -c 'set hidden' -c 'argdo $put =bufname(".")' -c 'wqa'
```